# Handling onLongClick of a child view in the Main Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, onlongclicklistener

I have a Main Activity that has a bunch of child views and then I have a ListView whose items are dynamically generated. I'd like to be able to long click any of these items and have this event handled in the Main Activity.

```
MainActivity
  LinearLayout
    ListView
      Item - (long click here)
```

Now I know how to subscribe the the onLongClick event of the dynamically created ListView item itself but that's in the adapter I use to create the items.

What I was hoping was, that I could simply subscribe to the onLongClick event of the Main Activity and I'd see the event from the dynamically created ListView item propagate up to the MainActivity. But that's not happening.

My MainActivity implements `View.OnLongClickListener`, like so

```
class MainActivity : Activity(), View.OnLongClickListener {
    override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
        Log.d("APP", "LongClicked: ")
        return true
    }
    ......
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to set the handler in the Activity itself. That is, for onClick, I would set `android:onClcik="onCLick"`, in the XML of the Main Activity, however, I don't see an option to do the same for `onLongClick`
Also, I have **not** set any attributes such as `android::longClickable="true/false"`

any of the views. I'm a bit confused by the true/false and what the actually mean.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I tried calling the `setOnLongCLickListener` on the ListView in the Main Activity, since I have access to the ListView there. Like so

```
availableZonesListView = findViewById(R.id.availableZonesListView)
availableZonesListView!!.onLongClickListener(this)
```

The MainActivity ('this') implements the View.OnLongClickListener and I see events coming in there when I long click directly on the MainActivity/Layout. But I don't see eventing coming in there when I long click on the items of the ListView

Comment: so where in your adapter are you calling `View#setOnLongClickListener` method? also you you need it for some kind of "context menu" or something?

Comment: When I set the onLongClick listener in the adapter (in the overridden getView() method) I can see the event there. However, I don't want to do it there. I'd rather react to it in the MainActivity/Layout. Hope that makes sense? Once I receive the event in the Main Activity/Layout, I'd like to call an MQTT Broker to do something.

Comment: so if you activity implements `View.OnLongClickListener` then when creating the adapter in your activity simply pass `this` to your adapter constructor - then you will be able to use it when calling `setOnLongClickListener` inside `getView` method

Comment: The adapter is being assigned to the ListView in a handler. I'd rather not pass the Main Activity down to the Handler, and then from the handler to the adapter. What I was expecting is for events in child views to automatically propagate up to the parents and eventually to the MainActivity/Layout

Comment: Handler? what Handler? `android.os.Handler`? mybe post your relevant code...

Comment: I have a handler (since I'm on a different thread than the UI thread) where I receive information for the ListView items I'm creating dynamically. So are you saying then, that if a child view does not handle an event, that event does not automatically, bubble up to it's parent and if the parent doesn't handle the event it doesn't bubble up to its parent etc.?

Comment: if you want to call `setOnLongClickListener` on parent `ListView` then you will miss the info about what particular list item was long clicked and i think you need it, dont you?

Comment: Yes, I do need the originating view that received the actual event. That's how it would work say in HTML and other UI architectures I've used (such as C# UWP applications, WinForms and host of others) where events bubble up to parents but one has access to the "thing" that was clicked. I did try calling setOnLongClickListener on the ListView in the MainActivity. But I don't see the listener being called.

Comment: That's why you need to do that inside getView method OR use context menu (I would personally do that) by calling registetForContextMenu or something similar

Comment: 'registetForContextMenu', OK I take a look at that. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry "register" of course, it's Activity method

Comment: and i would use "context menu" since simple long click should not invoke any direct actions as it can be "long" clicked by mistake - with "context menu" you have to confirm your action with an intentional click on menu item

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know how to subscribe the the onLongClick event of the dynamically created ListView item itself but that's in the adapter I use to create the items.

```
public MainActivity extends .. implements MyClickListener {

 ... onCreate {
     ... =  new MyAdapter(yourParams, this); // `this` is the new param 

 }

  @Override
  public void onAnyItemLongClicked() {
       // Do whatever you want
  }


}
```

Create your new interface:

```
interface MyClickListener {

   void onAnyItemLongClicked();

}
```

Then in your adapter where you *"Now I know how to subscribe the the onLongClick event"*. It would be something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter {

    // other fields
    private final MyClickListener listener;


    public MyAdapter(otherParams, MyClickListener listener) {
        .. assign other params
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}

// However you set your item click listener (in getView)

adapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          listener.onAnyItemLongClicked();
     }
});
```

This will propagate the click event from the adapter to the activity.

(I had to improvise a bit because you didn't share many code details)

Comment: What I was expecting/hoping for was that event in child views would automatically propagate up to the parent and eventually reach the MainActivity/Layout. From what you're suggesting, I'm having to pass a reference to the listener from the MainActivity to (in my case) to a handler and then from the handler to the adapter. I'm trying to avoid doing this.